# How exactly Apple Time Machine backups are encrypted?

Tags: encryption, backup

I have a USB SSD that I use for Time Machine backups. I have backup encryption enabled.

What keys exactly are used to encrypt the backup? Does Apple have any of those keys? How safe it is to keep this SSD in an unsafe location (suppose I have some critical information on it)?

Answer (score 1):

The keys for encrypting the backup are created on your local machine when you enable encryption.

Apple does not get a copy of your encryption keys (unless ofcourse you yourself send them a copy somehow).

Note: The encryption keys are protected by a passphrase - and that passphrase is normally stored in your Keychain. if you have "iCloud Keychain" enabled, you would be storing a copy of the passphrase on Apple's servers. It would be end-to-end encrypted though, meaning that Apple (given that the system is secure) wouldn't have access to it.

Assuming that you choose a long and hard to guess passphrase, this type of encryption is safe for "ordinary home users".

You will need to do an individual assessment in your case, as "safe", "unsafe location" and "critical information" means different things to different people. I.e. there's a difference between ensuring that your sister is not going to read your personal diary when storing it in your kitchen -- and ensuring that a national state does not access nuclear weapons secrets when storing them in the hands of their intelligence service.

Comment: does time machine also use the apfs encrypted file format?

Comment: Yes. On a modern macOS system, enabling encrypted Time Machine backups means that the APFS volume on the USB SSD will be recreated as an APFS encrypted volume.

Comment: "Apple does not get a copy of your encryption keys": Note that the key will be saved in the keychain, and if iCloud keychain sync is enabled, it will be stored on Apple's iCloud servers. [As described here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303), Standard data protection is the default setting, which means that the iCloud data encryption keys are secured in Apple data centers, and only certain data is end-to-end encrypted. While Apple says that keychain data is end-to-end encrypted, you must reply on them, as I wouln't know how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: @not2savvy I know I'm being a bit technical now, but there was a reason it was like that in my answer. You're not correct in saying that the encryption key is saved in the keychain and synced with iCloud Keychain. That's not how it works. What is saved is only the keyphrase. I'll amend my answer to clarify this

Comment: @jksoegaard Agreed, but the practical difference is small.

Comment: Is the drive encrypted and separately the backups in the drive? I.e. if two people have access to the drive for their backups can they read each others files?

Comment: No, for a USB attached drive, the whole drive is encrypted as such. So two users backing up to the same drive would have access to both backups.